# What happen if we terminate alter partition query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, kill

I've a huge table in SQL Server with more than 370 million records. Recently we did partitioning to improve query performance and it took around 9 hours and 37 minutes to finish so our websites was down for this time.

I am wondering if we can safely kill such alter process if it's taking long time or killing partitioning can damage the table data?

Below are the queries which I am running to alter partition by date range.

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME SCHEMENAME NEXT USED PART3
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION FUNCTIONNAME() SPLIT RANGE ('2014-12-31')
```

Comment: It might have been worth trying it in a test environment first before you made a change in production

Comment: And remember that quite often the operations are done in parallel, but rollback is single threaded, so many times it can take for example 4x longer time to rollback than what the process has taken so far

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, it is called rollback.

Since you don't show your Query or Script, we cannot assume what you are doing.

Can you show your script?

Comment: While I don't have the magic pill or bullet for you..  I would start here - http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/partitioning-in-sql-server-managing-sliding-window-scenario.html  If using Google, try the following: +ALTER +PARTITION +ROLLBACK what is important is the the "+" in your Google Query states it must have a keyword in your result.  Conversely (or opposite) the "-" (no quotes) tells Google to no include a term in your results.